# Can I know when Firefox Tracking Protection is turned on in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tracking, tealium

I have an application running with Tealium. Some features of the platform doesn't work when I access in Firefox and the tracking protection is turned on (In "always" mood) .

I want to  show an alert when the application detects Firefox tracking protection in mood "Always" to say "You have tracking protection activated and some features will not work in the platform" with java script.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a new extension in Tealium, and then, in that extension, detect whether or not tracking protection is turned on in Firefox (here's SO on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959324/how-to-detect-if-a-user-is-using-tracking-protection-in-firefox-42)). You can then display a popup, initiate an ajax, or redirect to another page if tracking protection is turned on.