# How to detect if a user is using 3rd party tracking cookie blocking in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, privacy

With the latest versions of Firefox the Advanced Privacy Protection is enabled per default.

Is there a way to check if a user has this enabled? I tried doing a regular 3rd party cookie check. But only the cookies of the major ad platforms are blocked.

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

I already unsuccessfully tried the following methods:

- [How to detect if a user is using tracking protection in Firefox 42+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959324/how-to-detect-if-a-user-is-using-tracking-protection-in-firefox-42)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection